# TextView con dos colores de texto en Android usando Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android

Estoy recibiendo tramas de `String` de dos canales diferentes y quiero mostrarlos en un solo `TextView` pero con dos colores diferentes, para ello estoy usando `Html.fromHtml()` para colorear la segunda trama, funciona el cambio de color pero por algún motivo me elimina el caracteres especiales de cambio de lines ("\n") y el `textview` lo muestra así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando en su lugar debería el `textview` debería mostrar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí esta mi código, alguien me podría decir como corregir esto?

```
 mDumpTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1_ReadValues);
 mScrollView = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.sc1_Scroller);
 .
 .

 public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        switch (msg.what) {
            case UsbService.SYNC_READ:
                String buffer = (String) msg.obj;
                if(msg.arg1 == 0){
                    mActivity.get(). mDumpTextView.append(buffer);
                }else if(msg.arg1 == 1){
                     mActivity.get().mDumpTextView.append( Html.fromHtml( redB + buffer + colorEnd ) );
                     mScrollView.smoothScrollTo( 0, mDumpTextView.getBottom() );
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Usando  Html.fromHtml(...)  los "\n" no se representarán como saltos de linea, te sugiero convertirlos a "<br>".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En este caso te sugiero reemplazar los `\n` por `<br>`

```
  String buffer = (String) msg.obj;
  buffer = buffer.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
```

de esta forma usando `Html.fromHtml(...)` se representarán los saltos de linea.

> [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/br) El elemento HTML line break 
>  produce un salto de línea en el
>   texto (retorno de carro).

---

Ejemplo:

```
    TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);

    String buffer = "Hola\n<font color=\"green\">amigo</font>\n<font color=\"#ff9900\">Stackoverflow</font>...\n<font color=\"red\">e foarte mișto!</font>\n<b>Jorgesys</b>";

    buffer = buffer.replaceAll("\n", "<br>");
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(buffer, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(buffer));
    }
```

En el `TextView` mostrara la siguiente información :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]