# Colorear un string en ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-layout

Básicamente no se si habrá alguna posibilidad de colorear un string. Tengo una lista que le estoy insertando strings y solo quisiera saber si se puede.
Por ejemplo

```
String texto="Rojo"+arrayList.get(i);
```

Que el elemento del array sea negro y el `Rojo` en rojo.
Esto lo muestro en un `ExpandableListView`. Lo he intentado con poner así

```
String texto="\033[31m Rojo"+arrayList.get(i);
```

Pero no colorea.

Comment: La pregunta es muy ambigua: si el String se va a mostrar en un WebView, se puede colorear con HTML y CSS, si lo vas a mostrar en un TextView tienes la propiedad textColor... etc

Comment: Lo muestro en un ExpandableListView

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki cuando realices preguntas, trata de agregar la mayor información posible para que la comunidad entienda que tratas de realizar y te ayude de mejor forma =), revisar [ask],  saludos!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si deseas que el elemento del array sea de color negro y el texto "Rojo" en color rojo:

```
String texto="Rojo"+arrayList.get(i);
```

agrega código `html` por ejemplo usando `<font>` y definiendo los colores rojo (`#ff0000`) y negro (`#000000`), y al agregarlo al `TextView` del `ExpandableListView` usa el método `Html.fromHtml()` para obtener el texto con estilo visualizable de la cadena HTML proporcionada:

```
String texto="<font color=\"#ff0000\">Rojo</font>"+"<font color=\"#000000\">"+ arrayList.get(i) + "</font>";

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
    textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
} else {
  textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(texto));
}
```

Revisa :

[TextView con dos colores de texto en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/222300/textview-con-dos-colores-de-texto-en-android)