# mi diseño de android studio no es igual que en mi dispositivo- Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Podrían ayudarme porfavor?
He Hecho un recyclerview y va todo bien

al momento de recuperar datos de un string.xml a otra actividad me sale todo en un solo texto.
Hice 2 texview que se muestran abajo en la imagen.
[image: app probado en mi movil]

El de color blanco el texto, se recupero con putextra de un recyclerview.

El de color rojo es un texview normal que coloque para ver si era el problema de mi dispositivo.

he probado mi app en mi android fisico, y no me quedó como esta en el diseño de android studio

En la imagen de abajo, En el texview de background rojo, ahí si me sale maso menos como lo coloque algunos negritas en los strings.xml

**Pero en el texview blanco,** antes del texview de color rojo me sale todo en texto y no como el texview de background rojo

Como podría arreglarlo para que ambos texview estén iguales?

Este es mi String

```
<string name="app_name">myrecicler4</string>
  <string name="textoprueba">
    <b>Esto es un texto</b>
    <br></br>
    <div></div>
    <div> ya que para eso se necesita de codigos html sin
        embargo eso es un poco confuso ya que tomaria demasido
    tiempo en hacerlo ahora con todos los pasos tenemos que hacerlo</div>
</string>

<string name="mitexto1">
    <b>Esto es un texto</b>
    <br></br>
    <div></div>
    <div> ya que para eso se necesita de codigos html sin
        embargo eso es un poco confuso ya que tomaria demasido
    tiempo en hacerlo ahora con todos los pasos tenemos que hacerlo</div>
   </string>
```

Mi activity #2 y su clase en el que recibo los datos

```
class DetallesActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detalles)

    val recibirtitulo = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_titulo2)
    val recibirimagen = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.iv_imagen2)
    val recibirtexto = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_recibirdatos)

    val bundle : Bundle? = intent.extras
    val recibirtitulos1= bundle!!.getString("tituloss")
    val recibirimagenes1 = bundle.getInt("imageness")
    val recibirtextos2 = bundle.getString("textoss")


    recibirtitulo.text = recibirtitulos1
    recibirtexto.text = recibirtextos2
    recibirimagen.setImageResource(recibirimagenes1)
}
```

El layout de la actividad #2

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/iv_imagen2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/image_kfc"></ImageView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_titulo2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Aqui va el titulo"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/tv_recibirdatos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/mitexto1"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp">

</TextView>

<TextView
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@color/rojo"
    android:text="@string/textoprueba"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>
```

ESTO ES EL ACTIVITY PRINCIPAL DONDE COLOCO LOS VALORES DEL STRING PARA ENVIARSELOS A LA ACTIVIDAD #2 - en el NEWS es donde uso el string.xml

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    imageid = arrayOf(
        R.drawable.image_corazon,
        R.drawable.image_molesto,
        R.drawable.image_marco,
        R.drawable.image_kfc,
        R.drawable.image_inuyasha
    )

    textid = arrayOf(
        "este es el primero",
        "ese es el segundo",
        "este es el tercer",
        "este es el cuarto",
        "y este es el ultimo en el que me demore mas de una eterniad en aprender el recycler view"
    )
    news = arrayOf(
        getString(R.string.mitexto1),
        getString(R.string.mitexto2),
        getString(R.string.mitexto3),
        getString(R.string.mitexto4),
        getString(R.string.mitexto5)
    )

    val newreciclerview = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.mi_recicler)
    newreciclerview.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    newreciclerview.setHasFixedSize(true)

    newarraylist = arrayListOf<Datos>()
    getUserdata()

    var adapter = adaptorDeDatos(newarraylist)
    newreciclerview.adapter = adapter
    adapter.setOnItemClickListener(object : adaptorDeDatos.onItemClickListener {
        override fun onItemClick(position: Int) {
            //Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity,"haz hecho click en. $position",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity,DetallesActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("tituloss", newarraylist[position].eltitulo);
            intent.putExtra("imageness", newarraylist[position].unaimagen);
            intent.putExtra("textoss", news[position]);
            startActivity(intent)

        }
    })
}

private fun getUserdata() {
    for (i in imageid.indices) {
        val news = Datos(imageid[i], textid[i])
        newarraylist.add(news)
    }
}
```

Comment: A que te refieres con "me sale todo en texto" en esto que comentas"Pero en el texview blanco, antes del texview de color rojo me sale todo en texto y no como el texview de background rojo"?

Comment: gracias por tu respuesta, osea el texview rojo y el texview blanco tienen que ser iguales.

Pero no quedan iguales, el texview blanco es un texto que recibe datos de un recyclerview.. y el texto rojo es un texview normal. ademas en android studio en el diseño se muestra todo lo que use en los string.xml,

Comment: ah, te refieres a que no tiene el mismo formato, por ejemplo "Esto es un texto" debería ser en letra tipo "bold".

Answer (score 0):

Si no se obtiene el mismo formato en el texto : "Esto es un texto", lo puedes lograr agregando código html , en este caso definirlo como texto bold `"<b>Esto es un texto</b>"`  y usar `Html.fromHtml()`, ejemplo:

```
String myText ="<b>Esto es un texto</b>  ya que para eso se necesita de codigos html sin embargo...";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(content, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
```

al mostrar en el `TextView` el texto, este se mostraría con el formato que deseas.

> **Esto es un texto**  ya que para eso se necesita de codigos html
> sin embargo...

Revisa esta respuesta:

[TextView con dos colores de texto en Android usando Html.fromHtml()](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/222300/textview-con-dos-colores-de-texto-en-android-usando-html-fromhtml)